# Align particle objects relative to parent mesh

Tags: particles, dupli-groups

I'm trying to put an object on the vertices of another object (crosses on a sphere) but I would like all the crosses to be parallel to the sphere's surface, not sticking out.

This is my current setup (using particles):

[image]

Comment: Set physics to "no".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "Rotation" panel of your particle system, choose "*Normal*" as your "*Initial Orientation*" (and possibly *Phase: 0*).

If your crosses are now sideways (this might not be your case), edit your original cross object in *Edit mode* (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and rotate it so that it lays on its side.

Better explained with pictures:

[image]

(P.S. as pointed out in the comments, if you want the particles to stay in place you should set "*Physics*" to "*No*")

---

Edit: in the comment you mention that you would like the "cross" instances to **follow the sphere during animation**. There are three different approach to this problem, which I'll not explain in detail as they are not the topic for this question:

1. **either** *Apply* the "ParticleSystem" modifier: this will make all the crosses real objects. Then you'll select all this objects and the sphere, and set parent (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) to make they follow the sphere.
2. **or** make a ParticleSystem of the "Hair" type instead of "Emitter". Several settings must be changed then.
3. **or** don't use a ParticleSystem at all, and use [DupliVerts](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliverts.html) instead.

Comment: I was trying that, but in object mode so it didnt work at first.

Comment: @СрђанХрњак In principle, you could do it in object mode, provided that after rotating you do Ctrl+A > "Apply rotation". That wouldn't allow you a live preview, though

Comment: Any way to keep them aligned during rotation of sphere (animation)? They are rotating around its own axis too. I tried to set the same animation for origin object itself (36 frames 10 degrees each) but without effect.

Comment: @СрђанХрњак see my edit

Answer (score 1):

Use "align rotation with the snapping target" in the footer of the 3Dview. You can choose dot or plane for snapping your cross.
See image joint: snap.png.[image]